# Fetching properties based on client's profile

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

How to fetch properties that is based on client's profile.

For example, If Client enable `spring.profiles.active=dev`, Service should fetch properties from `clien-dev.properties`

Answer (score 1):

If you rename your file to `application-dev.properties`, this should work out of the box.

More Info: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Brixton.SR6/#_quick_start